# Why are all textures rendering differently?

Tags: rendering, texturing

As you can see in the bottom right, the textures that appear when I render as completely different from what I have and get when I export as obj+mtl.  I believe this is because I used an old object and edited/overwrote the textures on the walls, but how can I get rid of those original ones?  I need to get the render to use as a png or jpg format.
[image: image:]

Comment: Hi. I think if there's something important we need to see in a screenshot it should probably be a bit bigger.

Comment: The screenshot just shows the render view in the bottom right, where you can see the textures on the walls are completely different from in the main view.

Comment: Yes, I know the screenshot shows it. I'm saying that, in general, if something is important to see, it should be made far bigger so that users can see it *easily*.